# Localize records and update with DataHandler

Tags: typo3

It is possible to localize records by using the "localize" command of the DataHandler

```
$cmd[self::TABLE_NAME] = [
  uid_of_the_original_record => [
    'localize' => language_uid,
  ]
];
$this->dataHandler->start([], $cmd);
$this->dataHandler->process_cmdmap();
```

This correctly adds a translated record to the DB, but with the copied strings of the original record. How is it possible to edit the properties of the localized record? By using the update command afterwards? If so, how do I get the uid of the added localization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually create localizations using the data map instead:

```php
$data[self::TABLE_NAME] = [
    'NEW123' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => <language-uid>,
        'l10n_parent' => <original-record-uid>, // Optionally also l10n_source
        // Other fields
    ],
];
$this->dataHandler->start($data, []);
$this->dataHandler->process_datamap();
```

This way you can directly set other fields when creating a localization.

Comment: Thanks. Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to run `localize` and put the translated content in there at the same time.

There are two options I can see:

1. Get all translated elements (by the original UID you have) and set the translated content in each of them afterwards
2. Hook into `processCmdmap_postProcess` or `processCmdmap_afterFinish` and put the translated content into it

I had the same issue with an importer and used option 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer which sounds good to me. I opened another datahandler after creating the original record, as it seems a bit faster to me. Thanks...